# How to override product details page in custom module

Tags: magento2, module, override-block

I create a module, then create files `details.phtml` under `app/code/Namespace/Module/view/frontend/templates/product/view` and create `catalog_product_view.xml` under `app/code/Namespace/Module/view/frontend/layout` .

`catalog_product_view.xml` code is

```
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="product.info.main">
        <container name="product.info.afterprice" after="product.info.price" label="Product info afterprice" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="product-info-after-price">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="details" template="Namespace_Module:product/view/details.phtml" />
        </container>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
```

but not working . How to override ?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to overide `details.phtml` then you need to write this code.

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
      <referenceBlock name='product.info.details'>
           <action method='setTemplate'>
                 <argument name='template' xsi:type='string'>Namespace_Module:product/view/details.phtml</argument>
            </action>
      </referenceBlock>
</referenceContainer>
```

Or

```
 <referenceContainer name="content">
    <referenceBlock name='product.info.details'>
      <arguments>
        <argument name='template' xsi:type='string'>Namespace_Module:product/view/details.phtml</argument>
    </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>
 </referenceContainer>
```

Comment: Not work it call my child theme path yet . Can you please explain briefly ,to create a extension for details page. What are the folders and path and code .

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code..

```
 <referenceContainer name="product.info.main">
         <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="custom.details" template="Namespace_Module:product/view/details.phtml" after="product.info.price"/>
</referenceContainer>
```